# Firebase Crash Reporting API/Notifications

Tags: firebase, firebase-crash-reporting

I've been looking around for a while now, but haven't been able to find a way to send out notifications about Firebase crashes.  I have found/enabled email notifications for these crashes, but I was hoping for an API that I could use to integrate them into Slack or something a bit more actionable than email. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

*firebaser here*

You will automatically get emails upon certain type of crash reports: new crash types and regressions. For example if a type of crash that you had fixed reoccurs, the system will send you an email to alert you to this regression.

But there is no API (yet) for getting called when a crash is registered on the server. It sounds like a good feature though, so I'd recommend that you [file a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/).

The best you can do right now is to trigger such an action from the client that reports the crash.

Comment: As an FYI, emails get sent every 24 hours or so.  So if you're wondering where your email is, you'll probably just have to wait for it.